# p4v client display current version of worspace

Tags: perforce

How to view the current revision of workspace in p4v client ?

What is the command line equivalent of the following command

```
p4 changes -m1 $PWD/...#have**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the Submitted Changes tab to show changes as of a certain revision, including what's synced to your client.

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4v/using.filters.html